# Save my work for later and revert to HEAD revision

Tags: svn

I know this might be a very basic question about SVN, but it's hard to search for it with few words.

Let's say I'm working on a ticket `#2015` where I had to make changes in the files `index.html` and `app.js`, but for some reason this ticket is now impeded and I'm waiting for something so I can continue to work on it.

So to not be idle, now I will start to work on ticket `#2047` let's say, which will include changes to file `blue-theme.css` and also `index.html`.

Assuming that I'm working with Subversion, which are the most appropriate operations I could use to not lose my work on ticket `#2015`, but also not commit those changes to file `index.html` as if they belong to ticket `#2047`?

Comment: I believe you're referring to what git refers to as "[stashing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)", and what SVN calls "shelving".  It's on the [roadmap](http://subversion.apache.org/roadmap.html) but keeps getting pushed later and later.

Comment: Use a branch in the first place, and commit work to that branch while switching to another branch.  Or secretly use `git svn` and save your temporary stuff with `git stash`.  This also substantially simplifies the use of temporary, personal branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Subversion way would be to create a branch for each ticket. Once you're confident that your ticket is closed, you do a final merge from `trunk` to the ticket branch, test it, and then merge the branch back into `trunk`.

**Example**

Let's assume you have the following setup in your repo:

```
^/trunk
^/branches
```

Let `trunk` be your "stable" repository while you do bug fixing in branches (a common workflow pattern for using Subversion). Then, your situation from the question could be handled as follows:

1. Create branch for ticket 2015: `svn cp path/to/repo/trunk path/to/repo/branches/ticket-2015`
2. Check out ticket branch: `svn co path/to/repo/branches/ticket-2015`
3. Work on issue 2015 in your working copy `ticket-2015` and commit as you like.
4. Start working on ticket 2047 by creating a new branch for it: `svn cp path/to/repo/trunk path/to/repo/branches/ticket-2047; svn co path/to/repo/branches/ticket-2047`
5. At some point you are satisfied with the work on 2047 and you decide to reintegrate:

   - You do a final merge from `trunk`: `cd ticket-2047; svn merge ^/trunk; svn commit`
   - You check if everything still works
   - You reintegrate by checking out a working copy of `trunk`, merging your branch, and committing it: `svn co path/to/repo/trunk; cd trunk; svn merge ^/branches/ticket-2047; svn commit`
6. Once your branch is reintegrated, you can delete it from the repo (don't worry, the history will of course be preserved, nothing ever gets *really* deleted from svn): `svn rm path/to/repo/branches/ticket-2047`
7. You continue with the same approach for ticket 2015

Following this approach you have some advantages:

- it is easy to work with multiple people on one issue
- it is easy to do automatic testing (if you have a system set up for it)
- none of your changes for either ticket get lost, and
- there will be no mixup whatsoever between the two tickets

Comment: Now that's a fantastic answer, not only provides an excellent answer to my question but also explains a technique that can be used to avoid this problem and organize the repositories! I wish I would have read something like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option: create a new working copy. Simply `svn checkout` your project to a new location, leaving your old working copy with all its uncommitted work intact, and do the new work ticket in the new working copy.

You can accomplish the same thing by using normal filesystem commands (not svn copy) to copy your working copy to a new location, then using `svn revert` on the new location to discard the work in progress on the new working copy.

Advanced option: if you don't want two working copies, you can use [svn diff](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) (or in TortoiseSVN, "view unified diff") to export a textual diff of all your modifications. Save that to a file, then revert all your changes. Later, when you are done with your second ticket and want to restore your changes from the first ticket, use the [svn patch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html) command to re-apply the changes from the diff file.